# SVG :Check the mouse event point are lie on arc

Tags: svg, jquery-svg, svg.js

My Arc points is:

```
<path d="M493.2603764000869,382.72281891984284
A67.55,140.3392240243227,-92.82217050690554,0,0,583.1119384765625,263.44476318359375d">
```

And my mouse point is :

```
MouseX:567.9578247070312
mouseY:279.65753173828125
```

I want to find if mouseX and mouseY lies on arc or not.
Are there any library methods for checking this?

Comment: call elementFromPoint and see if it returns the element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint

Comment: But its a svg we cannot use html methods for this

Comment: and i have only a svg path and mouse point

Comment: Do explain **why** you can't use a method on the common Document interface? And I've no idea what your second comment means.

Comment: when we use document interface then its return whole svg .
and i need only path points instead of whole svg.

Comment: Again, I've no idea what this comment means I'm afraid. Perhaps if you edited your question to show why elementFromPoint does not get you what you want/expect to get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91009/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-nitesh-singh).